# Boiled beef bones and ended up with green marrow...is this normal?

Tags: marrow

I boiled beef bones that had a good bit of marrow in them and the marrow turned green. Can I still use as a soup base?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. From my experience, if the bones were good, i.e. they had no odor before boiling them the soup is fine, just taste and if you like it all is good.

Maybe one of the ingredients turned the marrow green.